# how to catch cause exception in scala?

Tags: scala

I faced this problem when I tried to catch neo4j ServiceUnavailabeException which was inside of Spark Exception. So I couldn't catch neo4j Exception directly. Here is my code:

```
    try {
      val dataFrame = neo4jClient.cypher(
               "match (d:News) " +
               "return d.uid as newsUID"
      ).loadDataFrame

      Some(dataFrame)
    } catch {
      case e: SparkException => println(e.getCause)
    }
```

The Result of println(e.getCause):

```
org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ServiceUnavailableException: Unable to connect to localhost:7683, ensure the database is running and that there is a working network connection to it
```

Here is my question how can I catch ServiceUnavailabeException directly?(mean How can I get the cause error directly?)

Comment: No you need to match on the cause, or code your on extractor

Comment: Yeah, you're right . I tried it and it works. tnx :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no 100% sure method but you can try going with

```
def unrollExceptionMessage(ex: Exception): String = {
   def go(child: Exception, parentMessage: String): String = Option(child) match {
     case None => parentMessage
     case Some(e) => go(e.getCause, e.getMessage)
   }

   go(ex.getCause, ex.getMessage)
}
```